# php code behaves different in Chrome and Mozilla browsers

Tags: php

I have a Create new account page. The form is in page named Register.php and once user submit it, it will go to Confirm.php, where it validates the field if everything is correct shows the " Account Created " Message.

> In Chrome. The error message is shown in Register.php and once all
>   fields are filled then only will show confirm.php. But in Mozilla, it
>   goes to Confirm.php and shows a blank page.

My code for Register.php is :

```
<div class="signup_form">
<form action="confirm.php" method="post" >

<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
    {
        echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['username'].'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['email'].'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$_SESSION['error']['password'].'</p>';
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }
?>


<p>
<font size="3" face="arial" color="gray"> <label for="username"><b> UserName*</b> </label> </font>
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" input style="height:33px" size = "50" size="30"/>

</p>
<p>
<font size="3" face="arial" color="gray"> <label for="email"><b> E-mail Address*</b> </label> </font>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email"  input style="height:33px" size = "50" size="30"/>
</p>


<p>
<font size="3" face="arial" color="gray"> <label for="password"><b> Password*</b> </label> </font>
<input name="password" type="password" id="password"   input style="height:33px" size = "50" size="30"/>
    </p>  
<p>
<input name="submit" type="image" src="images/submit.gif" value="submit"/>    </p>
</form>

</div>
```

and for Confirm.php code is :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('configdb.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if($_POST['username'] == '')
        {

            $_SESSION['error']['username'] = "User Name is required.";
        }
        if($_POST['email'] == '')
        {
            $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "E-mail is required.";
        }
            else
            {
                if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email']))
                {
                    $email= $_POST['email'];
                    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql1) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
                        $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "This Email is already used.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                $_SESSION['error']['email'] = "Your email is not valid.";
                }
            }
        if($_POST['password'] == '')
        {
            $_SESSION['error']['password'] = "Password is required.";
        }

        if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
        {
            header("Location: register.php");
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error());

            if($result2)
            {

            echo '<div>Your account is now active. You may now <a href="login.php">Log in</a></div>';   
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create new user form behaves different in Mozilla and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862736/create-new-user-form-behaves-different-in-mozilla-and-firefox)

Comment: Please don't repost questions. Instead, edit the original to improve content.

Comment: it has been deleted since lots of confusions.

Comment: Your Confirm.php is incomplete. You're saying if you submit the form in Chrome you see your error messages, but if you submit it with any mozilla browser, you just get a blank page? Do you really see a blank page, or do you just don't see any error messages? Maybe your session is not created in your mozilla browser. Cookieblockers?

Comment: @Basti : exactly. In chrome i can see error in Register.php itself and if no errors only it will go to confirm.php and echo out success message. But mozilla nothing happens

Comment: @Basti : In Mozilla, in Tools - Privacy - I have enabled Accept cookies from sites and Accept third party cookies

Comment: See Kolinks answer. He's got it right.

Comment: @harismahesh: how is reposting the exact same question supposed to help matters? It would be better for you to learn how to [write a question properly](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` combined with an `input type="image"` does not work as expected, because the browser should send `submit.x` and `submit.y` with the coordinates the image was clicked on.

Instead, try using `if($_POST)` to ensure the form was submitted, or maybe `isset($_POST['username'])` or some other field you KNOW the name of.